# Selecting Imageview from a table view cells

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, uitableview

I have a table view and have 5 rows in it.In each row i have 4 imageView on which images are shown .Now i want to select an image from the first row.How can i do it.Please help
Thanks,
Christy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create UIButtons with the images as subviews.
And with the button you call your actions.

Something like this:

// Initialize your subviews for the cell and Tag them
//...

```
NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

if(row==0)
    {
    UIImage* image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"];
    [yourbutton1 addSubview:image];}
```

// ...

```
else{...}

return cell;
```

.
.
.

Comment: ya i changed that to button now i want to select the button and do something like setting an image to other image view how can i do it.The button is inside the table view ,can i write anything in its click event ,if so then how can i do it.I am a fresher thats y askig all this

Comment: call a function like this:[yourbutton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(YOURFUNCTION:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Comment: [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(Click:UIControlEventTouchUpInside)];  its showing error ,my function name is Click,please check

Comment: [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(Click)
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
sorry have to do like this ..

Comment: you should be more specific! how you defined your function. did you initialiyed the button before? what kind of error?

Comment: thanks friend it worked ,,please help me one more time.now what i want is when i click on the button then a pop up screen has to come and show me the image which was on the button,please help with this also

Comment: and also i ahev 4 buttons so on evry buttons click i can write the same method ,,but how the method will distinguish that which button has called for the method and which image to display

Answer (score 0):

When you say "select an image from the first row", do you mean something like "let the user tap on an image in the first row and highlight it" ?

If so, then you will want to investigate the following:

You will need to link the ImageView (IV) with your model somehow. So your model is an array of 5 (for your rows) each containing an array of 4 images (to show in each row).

You could set the tag of each IV to indicate the offset in the array. So now you know which IV is being tapped by the combination of the row it is in, and the tag it has.

If you want an action to be performed when the user taps your image, have you considered using a UIButton object and putting the image in that instead?

You may also want to make your IV allow user interaction, because they do not by default.

`yourImageView.setUserInteractionEnabled = YES;`

Hope this helps, good luck.

Comment: ya i changed my image view to a button ,now what i shud do ,please explain.i am a fresher.

Comment: can u provide me a demo code or sample solution like that please